# I want to get best performance/solution with writing to/reading file

Tags: java, hashmap

I have next task: user will request info about game. If game exists in library just return value (info about game - object) by key (game title - String). If not, do some work and after work add new game to library. Of course, I need a file (because if app will stop, all data will be lost). I decided to store game in library in hashmap. But what kind of format I should use to file which will contains all my library? JSON? Or simple txt?

After each request I should check this file and return value if key match was found.

And how many steps it will take before writing new information?

1. Check if game exists in library (read file).
2. If exist, then return value from file.
3. If no, then do actions and add new info to HashMap, then rewrite new version hashmap into file?

Too many steps.

Can I do it better?

Comment: In Case of Performance: Any File I/O acces is slow, so just keep you HashMap, for your programm. Your reads can go directly to the HashMap. your wirts also, but they also should **append** a new line/object to you File (at best asynchronly, by a seperate singleton writer, which has a buffer for non persistet Objects). The only time you have to read the file, is on startup.

Comment: How about creating a solution that works first?  Then, once you have a working solution, you can measure the performance.  Only then, if the performance is poor, do you think about alternate solutions.  A simple text file should be sufficient for your needs.